# Centering the dropdown menu without width

Tags: html, css

I would like to center align a dropdown menu without using width to the parent menu li.

CSS:

```
ul{list-style: none;}
li{display: block; float:left; height: 20px; background: #999999; margin: 10px;      position:relative;}
li span{height: 100px; width: 100px; background:#6699FF;position:absolute; left:-50%;     display:none;}
li:hover span{ display: block;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Sample Content <span></span></li>
  <li>Sample Content Sample Content<span></span></li>
  <li>Sample Content<span></span></li>
  <li>Sample ContentSample ContentSample Content<span></span></li>
</ul>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/y5nh8/

Comment: I cant see any drop down menu (select tag) ?

Comment: Not a select tag but the content will be placed inside the <span> which will be shown on hovering the <li>

Comment: @dreamweiver, dropdown menu is a very common term in web development, it's not the same as dropdown list, combo box or select.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro:Ya thanks , i undestood bro :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples on the internet for this. For example, http://www.lateralcode.com/css-drop-down-menus/

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a question that's been answered a lot here in stackoverflow. My advice would be to use search for **css dropdown menu** or some similar query.

Btw, Google is your friend, here's a source for free dropdown menus, I'm guessing you'll find some suitable for what you want to accomplish: http://cssmenumaker.com/css-drop-down-menu.

Comment: Yes I have seen a lot of dropdown but either they are aligned to left or to the right of the parent menu. If they are center positioned specific width is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified  css of **span** check out

`li span{height: 100px; width: 100px; background:#6699FF;  display:none;margin:0 auto ;}`

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/y5nh8/2/)

Happy coding :)

Comment: Removing the "position: absolute;" will affect the adjacent elements.

Comment: @sdesigns:hey bro,I guess you can tick this as answer, as this would close the question and reduce the no of open questions :)

Comment: Ya but need to fix the position absolute :(

Comment: @sdesigns:ok, then i guess you can keep the position as relative , so that your elements will be in sync with adjacent elements